# how to get goldengate replication stats on awr report

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am not seeing goldengate's "replication statistics" on AWR report - gg and oracle version is 19. Does anything need to be done to be able to see gg replication stats on awr report?

Comment: Please write more information: database version, OGG version, what type of extract replicat (integrated/classic).

Comment: 19c for db and ogg version and extract/replicats are integrated.